# Can someone explain this : "Spark SQL supports a different use case than Hive."

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark, shark-sql

I am referring to the following link : [Hive Support for Spark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark#HiveonSpark-1.3ComparisonwithSharkandSparkSQL)

It says :

> "Spark SQL supports a different use case than Hive."

I am not sure why that will be the case. Does this mean as a Hive user i cannot use Spark execution engine through Spark SQL?

Some Questions:

- Spark SQL uses Hive Query parser. So it will ideally support all of Hive functionality.
- Will it use Hive Metastore?
- Will Hive use the Spark optimizer or will it build its own optimizer?
- Will Hive translate MR Jobs into Spark? Or use some other paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark SQL is intended to allow the use of SQL expressions on top of Spark's machine learning libraries. It allows you to use SQL as a tool (among others) for building advanced analytic (eg ML) applications. It is not a drop-in replacement for Hive, which is really best at batch processing/ETL.

However, there is also work ongoing upstream to allow Spark to serve as a general data processing backend for Hive. That work is what would allow you to take full advantage of Spark for Hive use cases specifically.

Comment: Thanks. A few questions: - Spark SQL uses Hive Query parser. So it will ideally support all of Hive functionality. Will it use Hive Metastore? - Will Hive use the Spark optimizer or will it build its own optimizer? - Will Hive translate MR Jobs into Spark? Or use some other paradigm?

Comment: IIRC, Spark SQL will use the Hive Metastore yes, so you'll be able to run all Hive queries. As for Hive-on-Spark, see [this blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/07/apache-hive-on-apache-spark-motivations-and-design-principles/), which describes design principles.